# Fade away content area, but leave nav bar/header & footer always there

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fade

I'm having trouble with my webpage (I'm just starting to learn CSS and HTML so I need explanations if possible) My webpage has a header, much like the one of Stackoverflow. I have it fixed to the top and use it as a nav bar to change through pages. I'd like to fade the content on the page, but have the nav bar stay how it is. I'd like to do the same with the footer too. I'm not sure how I'd go about excluding these elements from being effected. I have it working but it will fade the entire page.

Please help!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").css("display", "none");

    $("body").fadeIn(1100);

    $("a.transition").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);      
    });

    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: when you select `$("body")` you are selecting the entire page, including the header and footer. This is because the HTML for the header and footer are children of the `body` tag. You need to update the selector to be just for the content, at least for the `fadeOut` case. Without seeing your HTML that is as far as I can answer.

Comment: Here is my HTML, I follow what you mean but I'm not sure how I'd execute it. http://pastebin.com/u61VZFAM

Comment: Thanks for the code. If you take a look at the answer by @bpettijohn you can kind of see what you'd need to do, which is wrap your content either in one div or give it similar class names (or some other attribute) which you could use with jQuery to select only the elements  you want to hide.

Comment: I've just attempted but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've tried wrapping the content but I just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery fade method.

http://jsbin.com/mujuzori/2/edit

HTML:

```
<body>
<header>My Header</header>
<nav>Click here to make content disappear</nav>
<div>My Content</div>
<footer>My Footer</footer>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("nav").click(function(){
        $("div").fadeOut();
    });  
});
```

Comment: I have my HTML here pastebin.com/u61VZFAM is there any chance you could explain how I'd go about doing this? I literally started CSS and HTML a couple of days ago so I'm finding it slightly difficult to work out what I've done wrong.

Comment: It looks like your targeting the entire body. $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage); Try targeting the specific section of the page you want to fade out.